# Find the point on the closed segment between (0, 1) and (2, 0) that is closest to (1001, 1995)

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Find the point on the closed segment between (0, 1) and (2, 0) that is closest to (1001, 1995)

I do not understand what the question is asking or how to approach it

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t more to the question?

Comment: Like the word “closest”?

Comment: I’m guessing it’s supposed to be: “Find the point on the closed segment between (0, 1) and (2, 0) CLOSEST to (1001, 1995)”

Comment: @Joe yes! It should be "closest to"

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell$ be a line and $P$ be a point off $\ell$. There is a point $Q\in \ell$ at a minimum distance to $P$; further, the line ${QP}$ and $\ell$ are orthogonal, i.e. their slopes are negative reciprocals.

The line connecting $(0,1)$ and $(2,0)$ is $y=1-x/2$, with slope $-1/2$. Thus the slope of the line connecting $Q$ and $P$ has slope $2$. Use point-slope form to write an equation for the line through $P$ with slope $2$, and solve:
$$
2(x-1001)+1995=1-x/2
$$Here we get $x=16/5$, which gives $y=-3/5$. But this is not within the segment, so we pick the point on this segment closest to $(16/5,-3/5)$, which is $(2,0)$.